# How can I make my Blog category unindexed in Google?

Tags: blog, seo

My Blog posts can break my SEO, as they're not about the themes my website discusses. So how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` [meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) within your `<head>`.

Then look into [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) to add it specifically to your category pages.

Or alternatively, you can check if `$cat_id` is available:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

If it is available, then it is a category page.

**EDIT** Just add it in an IF statement:

```
if (is_category()){ 
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
}
```

**EDIT 2** You can add this code to your [category.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) file which you can find within your theme's folder. Add it within the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Did this answer help you? If so, please accept this as correct answer. You should consider doing this for your other questions as well.

Comment: Of course I do that, I just didn't get the time to implement this. So how do I add my Blog category in is_category()? The page you anchored on WP just tells me about the function and that it can be used to know whether a page is displayed or not...

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: I add that piece of statement in where exactly?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Done. How do I know that it'll only noindex my Blog category?

Comment: Just view source of a category page and a page that isn't a category.

Comment: No, I mean I have 15 or so categories I write in. If I add this code in my header, wouldn't it noindex all categories?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you want? If you want to target a specific category, then target the category ID like: **is_category( '9' );** - learn more about this in its codex page.

Comment: Okay, I'll head over there...